# TypeError: Cannot read property '_throwIfRoot' of undefined when using uploadBytesResumable with Firebase 9

Tags: firebase, react-native, file-upload, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase Storage (Firebase 9.17.1) with React Native to upload images to my app, an I'm getting the following TypeError when trying to upload an image.

> TypeError: Cannot read property '_throwIfRoot' of undefined

Here's the relevant code:

```
const uploadImage = (image) => {
  if (!image || !image[0]) return;
  const imageRef = ref(storage, `images/${user.uid}/${v4()}`);
  const blob = new Blob([image[0]]);
  console.log("Image", image[0]);
  console.log("Image ref", JSON.stringify(imageRef));
  console.log("Blob", JSON.stringify(blob));
  uploadBytesResumable(imageRef, blob).then(() => {
    console.log(`Image ${image[0]} uploaded`);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(`Error uploading image: ${error}`);
  });
};
```

In addition to the console.logs:

```
Image file:///Users/sbone/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DC33189A-8F5C-44A9-B983-CEF036FB6458/data/Containers/Data/Application/65130C56-39EB-4F7E-8AEE-610D4352C485/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540samuelbone%252FFish/ImagePicker/C847B1DF-47E1-426B-A66C-5729AF4A1A12.jpg
Image ref {"_service":{"app":{"_isDeleted":false,"_options":{"apiKey":"<redacted>","authDomain":"<redacted>.firebaseapp.com","projectId":"<redacted>","storageBucket":"<redacted>.appspot.com","messagingSenderId":"555998065991","appId":"1:555998065991:web:83ede821f1de1af3b94862","measurementId":"G-G0DL7304RR"},"_config":{"name":"[DEFAULT]","automaticDataCollectionEnabled":false},"_name":"[DEFAULT]","_automaticDataCollectionEnabled":false,"_container":{"name":"[DEFAULT]","providers":{}}},"_authProvider":{"name":"auth-internal","container":{"name":"[DEFAULT]","providers":{}},"component":{"name":"auth-internal","type":"PRIVATE","multipleInstances":false,"serviceProps":{},"instantiationMode":"EXPLICIT","onInstanceCreated":null},"instances":{},"instancesDeferred":{},"instancesOptions":{},"onInitCallbacks":{}},"_appCheckProvider":{"name":"app-check-internal","container":{"name":"[DEFAULT]","providers":{}},"component":null,"instances":{},"instancesDeferred":{},"instancesOptions":{},"onInitCallbacks":{}},"_firebaseVersion":"9.17.1","_bucket":{"bucket":"<redacted>.appspot.com","path_":""},"_host":"firebasestorage.googleapis.com","_protocol":"https","_appId":null,"_deleted":false,"_maxOperationRetryTime":120000,"_maxUploadRetryTime":600000,"_requests":{}},"_location":{"bucket":"<redacted>.appspot.com","path_":"images/7JxjB20scSUshwLLTdsWBS0BKWY2/7bfd844a-2b69-426c-9a83-183d2fff751a"}}
Blob {"_data":{"blobId":"0752f260-65bb-479d-9aec-a390e915b718","offset":0,"size":286,"type":"","lastModified":1677559280378,"__collector":{}}}
```

I get a 9 byte junk file uploaded instead of the image. I'm not sure what's causing the error or how to fix it. Can someone help me understand what's going on and how to resolve this issue? I'd be happy to provide any additional information. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code where you defined `_throwIfRoot` ? Meanwhile check this [document](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/javascript-promise-typeerror:-cannot-read-then-of-undefined)

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! I don't have the _throwIfRoot function defined anywhere, but I believe it is being used in my dependency. I know my code is failing on the   uploadBytesResumable() function though.

Comment: Can you confirm you have intialized the storage instance with [getStorage(app)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/create-reference#create_a_reference) properly and check you are using [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) correctly?